# execute 2 cubes in SSAS with SSIS package

Tags: process, ssis, package, cubes

I have 2 separate cubes in SSAS , I want to process these cubes with SSIS package but I want to process my cubes singly , this means that I dont want use full process and my goal is to process cubes singly . when I use "Analysis Services Processing Task" some times I get an error . is there another way to do that?

Comment: Why cant you have 2 ASP tasks called out separately and have a precedence constraint between them? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: what error have you received?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a profiler trace of Analysis Services.  Perofrm your action (i.e. Process Update) and view the analysis services command which will look something like

```
<Batch xmlns="...">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="...">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>Database</DatabaseID>
        <DimensionID>DimensionName</DimensionID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessUpdate</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

You can then create a SQL Job as type SQL Server Analysis Services Command to schedule each cube accordingly.